# How to add x-delay header on RabbitMQ message?

Tags: java, groovy, rabbitmq

I'm trying to add a header `x-delay` on my messages using a instance of `MessagePostProcessor` but it gives me an exception saying:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: MessageHeaders is immutable

```
import org.springframework.messaging.Message
import org.springframework.messaging.core.MessagePostProcessor
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class AmpqRoutingKeyStrategy {

    private static CUSTOM_DELAY = 120000

    MessagePostProcessor get() {
        return withDelay(CUSTOM_DELAY)
    }

    static MessagePostProcessor withDelay(Integer milliSeconds) {
        return new MessagePostProcessor() {
            @Override
            Message postProcessMessage(Message message) {
                message.getHeaders().put('x-delay', milliSeconds)
                return message
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The example above is used in many articles about this topic, I know that we have the option to add the `x-delay` header but how can I do it without raising this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/MessageHeaders.html) says:

> IMPORTANT: This class is immutable. Any mutating operation such as put(..), putAll(..) and others will throw UnsupportedOperationException.

The solution is to recreate the message:

```
static MessagePostProcessor withDelay(Integer milliSeconds) {
    return new MessagePostProcessor() {
        @Override
        Message postProcessMessage(Message message) {
            return org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder
                .fromMessage(message)
                .setHeader("x-delay", milliseconds)
                .build()
        }
    }
}
```